# What kind of worm is this?

Tags: zoology

What kind of worm is this? I’ve seen them in my bathroom and kitchen which are both ceramic tile. This morning I walked in the kitchen and this one just so happened to be dead. 
[image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Where do you live (country/region/type of ecosystem)? What is the approximate size? Did you notice any behaviour of interest? How fast do they move? Any other info?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that isnt a worm but a nonvenomous blind snake specie named *Indotyphlops braminus* 
[image]([Indotyphlops braminus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indotyphlops_braminus))  .([Brahminy Worm Snake](http://indiansnakes.org/content/brahminy-worm-snake) )